# How to make a page free of authentication using react context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I have just one page that should be open access to everyone who access to the application URL, but the useEffect of the AuthContext is firing without being called. I'm new with Context Api, anyone know what is wrong ?

The route that should be open is "/list/:id" and the component is "List.jsx".

AuthContext.jsx

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import firebase from "firebase"
import { auth } from "../services/firebase"

export const AuthContext = createContext()

export function AuthContextProvider(props){
    const history = useHistory()
    const [user, setUser] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
       
        const unsubscribre = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            
            if(user){         
                const {displayName, photoURL, uid} = user
  
                if(!displayName || !photoURL){
                  throw new Error('Missing information from google')
                }
          
                setUser({
                  id: uid,
                  name: displayName,
                  avatar: photoURL
                })             

            } else {
                history.push('/')
            }          
        })

        return () => {
            unsubscribre()
        }
    }, [])


    const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

        const result = await auth.signInWithPopup(provider)

        if(result.user){
            const {displayName, photoURL, uid} = result.user

            if(!displayName || !photoURL){
              throw new Error('Missing information from google')
            }
      
            setUser({
              id: uid,
              name: displayName,
              avatar: photoURL
            })          
        }
    }

    const signOut = async () => {
        await firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
            setUser(null)
            history.push('/')
        })        
    }

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, signInWithGoogle, signOut}}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

import {Home} from './pages/Home/Home'
import {Lists} from './pages/Lists/Lists'
import {CreateList} from './pages/CreateList/CreateList'
import {List} from './pages/List/List'

import { AuthContextProvider } from './contexts/AuthContext'
import './assets/styles/global.scss'

function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>        
          <Switch>
            <AuthContextProvider>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Home} /> 
              <Route path="/lists" component={Lists} /> 
              <Route path="/createlist/:id" component={CreateList} />
            </AuthContextProvider>
            {/* the page above should not have authentication */}
            <Route path="/list/:id" component={List} /> 
          </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

List.jsx

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AiOutlineClose } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { useParams, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from '../../components/Button/Button';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { Table } from '../../components/Table/Table';

import './styles.scss'

const customStyles = {
    content: {
      top: '50%',
      left: '50%',
      right: 'auto',
      bottom: 'auto',
      marginRight: '-50%',
      transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    },
  };

export function List(){
   
    const history = useHistory()

    const params = useParams()
    const listId = params.id

    const[list, setList] = useState()
    const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        getList()
    }, [])

    function openModal() {
        setIsOpen(true);
    }

    function closeModal() {
        setIsOpen(false);
    }

    const getList = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("/mock/lista_compartilhada.json");
        const data = await response.json()

        console.log(data)
        setList(data.list)
    }

    const handleCreateList = () => {
        history.push('/')
    }

    const handleGiveGift = () => {
        alert('presente dado')
    }

    return(
        <div className="share_list_area">
            <header>         
                <Button value="Criar Lista" onclick={handleCreateList}  background="blue" width={230}/>
                { list &&
                    <div className="list_info_area">                
                        <h1>{list.name} - {list.date}</h1>      
                    </div>
                  } 
            </header>
            <main>
                <section>
                    { list ? 
                       <Table itens={list.itens} click={openModal}/>   
                    :  <h1>Lista não encontrada.</h1>                    
                    }              
                </section>
            </main>

            <Modal
                isOpen={modalIsOpen}
                onRequestClose={closeModal}
                style={customStyles}
                contentLabel="Example Modal"
            >             
                <AiOutlineClose className="close-modal" size={24} onClick={closeModal} />
                <form className="form-create">
                    <div className="form-input">
                        <label>Seu nome:</label>
                        <input placeholder="ex: Guilherme" />
                    </div>
                    <Button value="Dar presente"  background="pink"/>
                </form>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please add whole codes in a sandbox

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` in `AuthContextProvider` will run on mount (i.e. empty array as dependency)

and since `AuthContextProvider` is used in App.js, it gets mounted as part of App and hence it calls its own `useEffect`.